# How to use GroupBy in an asynchronous manner in EF Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

When I use GroupBy as part of a LINQ query to EFCore, I get the error `System.InvalidOperationException: Client-side GroupBy is not supported`.

This is because EF Core 3.1 attempts to evaluate queries on the server-side as much as possible, as opposed to evaluating them on the client-side, and the call cannot be translated to SQL.

So the following statement does not work, and produces the error mentioned above:

```
var blogs = await context.Blogs
    .Where(blog => blog.Url.Contains("dotnet"))
    .GroupBy(t => t.BlobNumber)
    .Select(b => b)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Now apparently the solution is to use.AsEnumerable() or .ToList() before the call to GroupBy(), as that explicitly tells EF Core that you want to do the grouping client side. There is a discussion about this [on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17068) and [in the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#explicit-client-evaluation).

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Where(blog => blog.Url.Contains("dotnet"))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(t => t.BlobNumber)
    .Select(b => b)
    .ToList();
```

However, this is not asynchronous. How can I make it asynchronous?

If I change AsEnumerable() to AsAsyncEnumerable(), I get an error. If I instead try to change AsEnumerable() to ToListAsync() then the GroupBy() command fails.

I am thinking of wrapping it in a Task.FromResult, but would this actually be asynchronous? Or is the database query still synchronous and only the subsequent grouping is asynchronous?

```
var blogs = await Task.FromResult(context.Blogs
    .Where(blog => blog.Url.Contains("dotnet"))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(t => t.BlobNumber)
    .Select(b => b)
    .ToList());
```

Or if that doesn't work is there another way?

Comment: Even if that wasn’t there the issue seems to remain. (The example above is just one I threw together copying and pasting from elsewhere. My actual code does not use that function.)

Comment: Ok You should explicitly mention that. I'll remove my comment. then.

Comment: Either way though, I figure if using AsEnumerable solves the problem so easily, then there must be another easy way to do it but asynchronously. I just cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: I've simplified the example to get rid of that function.

Comment: Shortly, `AsAsyncEnumerable()` + `System.Linq.Async` package (and `AsQueryable()` for `DbSet`s inside if any)

Comment: @IvanStoev there's no reason, the OP isn't really grouping anything. The query is loading all detail rows and batching them, it doesn't aggregate anything. In fact, shouldn't that `Select(b=>b)` *ungroup* the groups?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `Select(b => b)` does nothing and can be skipped (not essential for the issue). The problem is what to put **before** `GroupBy` and let the code after compile and execute client side.

Comment: @IvanStoev right, it would need SelectMany to flatten. In that case, GroupBy is pointless too. The entire operation is a `ToLookup(t => t.BlobNumber)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Again, the concreted `Select` in the sample query is not essential for the question asked, which is *"How to use **GroupBy** in an **asynchronous manner** in EF Core 3.1?"*

Comment: @Gary you can use the System.Linq.Async package and `AsAsyncEnumerable()` to get real client-side async grouping. EF isn't involved here, you aren't *grouping* data in the SQL sense. You're loading individual rows and putting them in buckets by BlobNumber. You can speed this up with parallelization after loading, or by using the async LINQ operators

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the only way you have is just to do it something like this

```
var blogs = await context.Blogs
    .Where(blog => blog.Url.Contains("dotnet"))
    .ToListAsync();

var groupedBlogs = blogs.GroupBy(t => t.BlobNumber).Select(b => b).ToList();
```

Because GroupBy will be evaluated at client anyway

Comment: This is what I ended up going with. It is simple and it works.

Answer (score 8):

This query isn't trying to group data in the SQL/EF Core sense. There are no aggregations involved.

It's loading all detail rows and then batching them into different buckets on the client. EF Core isn't involved in this, this is a purely client-side operation. The equivalent would be :

```
var blogs = await context.Blogs
    .Where(blog => blog.Url.Contains("dotnet"))
    .ToListAsync();

var blogsByNum = blogs.ToLookup(t => t.BlobNumber);
```

**Speeding up grouping**

The batching/grouping/lookup operation is purely CPU bound, so the only way to accelerate it would be to parallelize it, ie use all CPUs to group the data eg :

```
var blogsByNum = blogs.AsParallel()
                      .ToLookup(t => t.BlobNumber);
```

`ToLookup` does more or less that `GroupBy().ToList()` does - it groups the rows into buckets based on a key

**Grouping  while loading**

A different approach would be to *load* the results asynchronously and put them into buckets as they arrive. To do that, we need `AsAsyncEnumerable()`. `ToListAsync()` returns all the results at once, so it can't be used.

This approach is quite similar to what `ToLookup` does.

```
var blogs = await context.Blogs
    .Where(blog => blog.Url.Contains("dotnet"));

var blogsByNum=new Dictionary<string,List<Blog>>();

await foreach(var blog in blogs.AsAsyncEnumerable())
{
    if(blogsByNum.TryGetValue(blog.BlobNumber,out var blogList))
    {
        blogList.Add(blog);
    }
    else
    {
        blogsByNum[blog.BlobNumber=new List<Blog>(100){blog};
    }
}
```

The query is executed by the call to `AsAsyncEnumerable()`. The results arrive asynchronously though, so now we can add them to buckets while iterating.

The `capacity` parameter is used in the list constructor to avoid reallocations of the list's internal buffer.

**Using System.LINQ.Async**

Things would be a lot easier if we had LINQ operations for IAsyncEnumerable<> itself. [This extension](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/tree/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async) namespace provides just that. It's developed by the ReactiveX team. It's available through [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/) and the current major version is 4.0.

With this, we could just write :

```
var blogs = await context.Blogs
    .Where(blog => blog.Url.Contains("dotnet"));

var blogsByNum=await blogs.AsAsyncEnumerable()   individual rows asynchronously
                          .ToLookupAsync(blog=>blog.BlobNumber);
```

Or

```
var blogsByNum=await blogs.AsAsyncEnumerable()   
                          .GroupBy(blog=>blog.BlobNumber)
                          .Select(b=>b)
                          .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Why reopening to just post a duplicate answer (`AsAsyncEnumerable()` + `System.LINQ.Async` package)? The first part of this answer doesn't make sense in this context. The question is (and the whole GitHub debate) what is the pattern of forcing async client evaluation in EF Core query. For synchronous LINQ it's simple `AsEnumerable()` and the rest goes through `Enumerable` LINQ.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I considered going with System.LINQ.Async, but then ended up going with Denis' suggestion since it required one less dependency and worked well for my simple use case. Will keep this package in mind for the future use though.