# .NET Core 3.1 - Linq - Select records grouped by a unique attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In .Net framework I had this working query:

```
IEnumerable<Cars> LatestCars = await _context.Cars.Where(x => x.IsActive == true && x.IsDeleted == false)
            .GroupBy(y => y.ManufacturerId)
            .Select(z =>
                z.OrderByDescending(k => k.ReleaseDate)
                .FirstOrDefault()
            )
            .OrderByDescending(l => l.ReleaseDate)
            .Take(5)
            .ToListAsync();
```

This basicly gets the latest 5 cars released by distinct manufacturers.

But when I switched to .NET Core. This query is not working anymore. And I have this error when I run it:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: (g.ManufacturerId), 
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: Cars
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
    IsNullable: False
)
)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.ReleaseDate)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Try to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59965647/how-to-use-groupby-in-an-asynchronous-manner-in-ef-core-3-1 , it may help you

Comment: I don's see what are you selecting in Select.

Answer (score 0):

EF Core, starting from version 3, throws an exception when an expression could only be executed locally. And actually the problem is not the `.OrderByDescending()` per se, but the fact that the query contains grouping, and grouping only supports `Select()` projections that aggregate the result to a scalar. Because only this can be translated into a SQL GROUP BY statement.

There is one handy way of dealing with this. If you have a `Manufacturer` model which contains an `IEnumerable<Car> Cars` navigational property, you can start from there, and that leads to a translatable query.

So, in your case this working query could be the following:

```cs
  Manufacturers.Select(m => m.Cars.OrderByDescending(c => c.ReleaseDate).FirstOrDefault())
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.ReleaseDate).Take(5)
```

*The downside is that you can have `null` values in this list, if a manufacturer has 0 cars, so normally it's a good idea to filter those out, but in this case the `OrderByDescending()` pretty much mitigates this.*

Another possible solution is to query a limited number of items, and then continue working locally:

```cs
  Cars.OrderByDescending(c => c.ReleaseDate).Take(100).ToList()
    .GroupBy(c => c.ManufacturerId).Select(g => g.First()).Take(5)
```

*The downside of this is that you can potentially end up having less than 5 results.*